# Salvar Status Code em variável e fazer verificação

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu preciso salvar o StatusCode e fazer uma verificação. Tenho o seguinte código:

```
using (HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(UrlApi)){}
```

Quando faço isso: `var teste2 = response.StatusCode;` o SatusCode retorna `BadRequest` mas não salva na variável e eu precisava fazer uma verificação, ex:                     `if(teste2.Equals("BadRequest")){//Faça algo}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro que faça a conversão do StatusCode para um inteiro, e logo após, faça as comparações desejadas.

Algo como:

```
var teste2 = (int)response.StatusCode;

if(teste2 == 400)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Bad Request");
}
else if(teste2 == 200)
{
   Console.WriteLine("OK");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar o enum `HttpStatusCode`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://httpbin.org");

        EnviarRequest(client, "uuid");

    }

    public static async void EnviarRequest(HttpClient client, string path)
    {
        using (var response = await client.GetAsync(path))
        {           
            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                Console.WriteLine("OK");

            if(response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
                Console.WriteLine("Not Found");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Só pra constar: eu escrevi essa resposta no dia 01, mas acabei esquecendo de postar.